# Robot Framework working with Spring Framework

Tags: spring, robotframework

It seems that Robot Framework has a trouble of instantiating a class that has "Autowired" annotations (i.e. getting null for those properties). Is there a way for Robot Framework to get around this? That is, to use classes that have used Spring wiring?

Comment: Can you share a sample code of where it is failing?

Comment: It's similar to this question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7023452/using-spring-wired-libraries-with-robotframework

I was wondering if anyone attempted again to do the same.