# Possible to autowire imported utility classes in Spring?

Tags: spring, autowired

I want to use data mappers, logger, transfromers, etc. in my Spring web projects. Is it possible to autowire an imported (jar) utility dependency, without wrapping it in some @Component or @Service class? Do we even want to do it that way, or should we just use a static reference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your utils, are based on **not static** methods, then this is simple:

If you use java based configuration, then just declare that util in an `@Bean` annotated method.

```
@Configuration
public class YourConfig {

   @Bean 
   public YourUtil util(){
      return new YourUtil ();
   }
}
```

in xml it could been as simple as:

```
<bean id="util" class="org.example.YourUtil" />
```

---

*The following is true, but it is not what was asked for:*

<strike>There are at least two other ways to inject beans in instances that are not created (managed) by Spring:</strike>

- (1) add `@Configurable` annotation to this class - this requires real AspectJ (compile-time or load-time -weaving)

  - @see Spring Reference Chapter [7.8.1 Using AspectJ to dependency inject domain objects with Spring](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#aop-atconfigurable)
  - @see this answer of mine https://stackoverflow.com/a/7007572/280244 for a quick "guide" to enable the `@Configurable` support
- (2) invoke [`SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnCurrentContext(this);`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/support/SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.html#processInjectionBasedOnCurrentContext-java.lang.Object-)

  - @see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6990767/280244) and its (two highes voted answers) for some ideas how to use

Answer (score 2):

You can only @Autowire a bean managed by Spring. So you have to declare your instance through some configuration : a bean in an xml file, or a @Bean method in a java configuration.

@Component are just automatically discovered and registered in the spring context.

Comment: I though the question was how to inject some external instance (from external bean) to a spring bean through @Autowire. Your answer are on how to inject spring bean to unmanaged external instance, the opposite ;-)